# puppetserver gem install adds gem but it's not available for custom functions in the puppet code

Tags: activerecord, puppet, jruby

I have simple setup: CentOS7 and Puppet7 running on it. Server is up and running.
I installed `activerecord-jdbcsqlite3-adapter` adapter for my custom function. This is what I can see on the server with `puppetserver gem list`

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

activemodel (6.1.7.3)
activerecord (6.1.7.3)
activerecord-jdbc-adapter (61.2 java)
activerecord-jdbcsqlite3-adapter (61.2 java)
activesupport (6.1.7.3)
bundler (default: 2.2.33)
cmath (default: 1.0.0)
concurrent-ruby (1.1.5)
csv (default: 3.2.5)
deep_merge (1.2.2, 1.0.1)
e2mmap (default: 0.1.0)
fast_gettext (1.1.2)
ffi (default: 1.15.4 java)
fileutils (default: 1.4.1)
forwardable (default: 1.2.0)
gettext (3.2.2)
hiera-eyaml (3.3.0)
highline (2.0.3)
hocon (1.3.1)
i18n (1.14.1)
io-console (default: 0.5.9 java)
ipaddr (default: 1.2.2)
irb (default: 1.0.0)
jar-dependencies (default: 0.4.1)
jdbc-sqlite3 (3.28.0)
jruby-openssl (default: 0.14.0 java)
jruby-readline (default: 1.3.7 java)
json (default: 2.5.1 java)
locale (2.1.3, 2.1.2)
logger (default: 1.5.1)
matrix (default: 0.3.0)
mini_portile2 (2.8.2)
minitest (5.18.0)
multi_json (1.15.0)
mutex_m (default: 0.1.0)
optimist (3.0.1)
ostruct (default: 0.5.5)
prime (default: 0.1.0)
psych (default: 3.3.4 java)
puppet-resource_api (1.8.16)
puppetserver-ca (2.5.0)
racc (default: 1.5.2 java)
rake-ant (default: 1.0.4)
rdoc (default: 6.3.3)
rexml (default: 3.2.5)
rss (default: 0.2.7)
rubygems-update (default: 3.2.33)
scanf (1.0.0)
semantic_puppet (1.0.4, 1.0.2)
shell (default: 0.7)
sync (default: 0.5.0)
text (1.3.1)
thwait (default: 0.1.0)
tracer (default: 0.1.0)
tzinfo (2.0.6)
webrick (default: 1.7.0)
zeitwerk (2.6.8)
```

[root@puppet-server certs]# puppetserver gem environment

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 3.2.33
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.6.8 (2022-10-24 patchlevel 0) [java]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /opt/puppetlabs/server/data/puppetserver/jruby-gems
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /root/.gem/jruby/2.6.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.372.b07-1.el7_9.x86_64/jre/bin/java -cp :/opt/puppetlabs/server/apps/puppetserver/puppet-server-release.jar:/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/facter.jar:/opt/puppetlabs/server/data/puppetserver/jars/* org.jruby.Main
  - GIT EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/git
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /opt/puppetlabs/server/data/puppetserver/jruby-gems/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /root/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: uri:classloader:/META-INF/jruby.home/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
     - ruby
     - universal-java-1.8
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /opt/puppetlabs/server/data/puppetserver/jruby-gems
     - /opt/puppetlabs/server/data/puppetserver/vendored-jruby-gems
     - /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_gems
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - "install" => "--env-shebang"
     - "update" => "--env-shebang"
     - "setup" => "--env-shebang"
     - "pristine" => "--env-shebang"
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /root/.rbenv/shims
     - /root/.rbenv/bin
     - /usr/local/sbin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /usr/bin
     - /opt/puppetlabs/bin
     - /root/bin
```

Here is code of my custom_function.rb (it prints list of all gems which can be "seeing" from the function invoked by puppet. (Output is below)):

```
require "timeout"
require "erb"
require "rubygems"
#require "activerecord-jdbcsqlite3-adapter"
#require "sqlite3"

#ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(:adapter => "sqlite3",
#                                        :database => "/my-db/sqlite.db",
#                                        :pool => 5,
#                                        :timeout => 10000)

# Documentation for the function
Puppet::Functions.create_function(:custom_function) do
  dispatch :custom_function do
    required_param 'String', :device_name
    required_param 'String', :template_name
  end

  def custom_function(device_name, template_name)
    my_local_gems = Gem::Specification.sort_by{ |g| [g.name.downcase, g.version] }.group_by{ |g| g.name }
    puts my_local_gems.map{ |name, specs|
      [
        name,
        specs.map{ |spec| spec.version.to_s }.join(',')
      ].join(' ')
    }
    puts RUBY_VERSION
  end
end
```

output:

```
>puppet lookup classes --compile
benchmark 0.1.0
bigdecimal 2.0.0
bundler 2.1.4
cgi 0.1.0.2
concurrent-ruby 1.1.9
csv 3.1.2
date 3.0.3
deep_merge 1.2.2
delegate 0.1.0
did_you_mean 1.4.0
etc 1.1.0
facter 4.3.1
fast_gettext 1.1.2
fcntl 1.0.0
ffi 1.15.5
fiddle 1.0.0
fileutils 1.4.1
forwardable 1.3.1
getoptlong 0.1.0
gettext 3.2.2
hiera 3.12.0
hiera-eyaml 3.3.0
highline 2.0.3
hocon 1.3.1
io-console 0.5.6
ipaddr 1.2.2
irb 1.2.6
json 2.3.0
locale 2.1.3
logger 1.4.2
matrix 0.2.0
minitest 5.13.0
multi_json 1.15.0
mutex_m 0.1.0
net-pop 0.1.0
net-smtp 0.1.0
net-ssh 4.2.0
net-telnet 0.2.0
observer 0.1.0
open3 0.1.0
openssl 2.1.4
optimist 3.0.1
ostruct 0.2.0
power_assert 1.1.7
prime 0.1.1
pstore 0.1.0
psych 3.1.0
puppet 7.24.0
puppet-resource_api 1.8.16
puppetserver-ca 2.5.0
racc 1.4.16
rake 13.0.1
rdoc 6.2.1.1
readline 0.0.2
readline-ext 0.1.0
reline 0.1.5
rexml 3.2.3.1
rss 0.2.8
scanf 1.0.0
sdbm 1.0.0
semantic_puppet 1.0.4
singleton 0.1.0
stringio 0.1.0
strscan 1.0.3
sys-filesystem 1.4.1
test-unit 3.3.4
text 1.3.1
thor 1.2.1
timeout 0.1.0
tracer 0.1.0
uri 0.10.0
webrick 1.6.1
xmlrpc 0.3.0
yaml 0.1.0
zlib 1.1.0
2.7.7
```

And if I add `require "activerecord-jdbcsqlite3-adapter"` I am getting error like:

```
Error: Could not run: cannot load such file -- activerecord-jdbcsqlite3-adapter
```

And finally. It works well if I run it in `puppetserver irb`:

```
[root@puppet-server ~]# puppetserver irb
irb(main):001:0> require "activerecord-jdbcsqlite3-adapter"
=> true
irb(main):002:0> ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(:adapter => "sqlite3", :database => "/db/sqlite.db")
=> #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionPool:0x2cd31214 @connection_klass=ActiveRecord::Base, @connections=[], @thread_cached_conns=#<Concurrent::Map:0x5d32f5db entries=0 default_proc=nil>, @checkout_timeout=5.0, @mon_data_owner_object_id=4020, @now_connecting=0, @pool_config=#<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PoolConfig:0x16f2d883
...
...
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puppet's `puppetserver` and `puppet` subsystems have separate Ruby installations.  The former is JRuby, whereas the latter is MRI / CRuby.  The `puppetserver gem` command operates on the Ruby supporting `puppetserver`, but for your custom function you probably need the one supporting `puppet`, as that's what the catalog compiler uses.  To install gems for that one, use the `gem` command bundled alongside the `puppet` command, typically at `/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/bin/gem`.